# Sum over binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I want to find out if the following sum has a closed form:
$$\sum_{j=0}^N{j+k-1\choose k-1}{N-j+k-1\choose k-1}$$

I tried to rewrite the sum such that I could use the following form of the Vandermonde identity:
$$\sum_{m=0}^n{m\choose j}{n-m\choose k-j}={n+1\choose k+1}$$
but I couldn't arrive at any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are doing good! Using what you put there you will need $n-(j+k-1)=N-j+k-1$ implies $n=N+2k-2$ and you also have that $2k-2-(k-1)=k-1$ So take the $k$ in the second equation to be $2k-2.$

Comment: yea, but if I substitute $m=j+k-1$, the sum does not start from 0 afterwards. I can write it in terms of the sum that starts from 0, but a term appears that has the same form as the starting sum.

Comment: Notice that this is not very important because $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $n<k$ so is like your LHS starts at $m=j$